# Javascript changing row color back to original color

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im wanting to know how to have the functionality of this code but when I uncheck the code it resets back to the background color that it was. In the script below it changes back to white as you can see. The rows im working with are set the class(background color) via php in a foreach loop depending on whats in the array. I have only seen examples like below where it sets your color if checked, else...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox:not(#checkall)').live('click', function(event) {
        if ($("#checkall").attr('checked') == true && this.checked == false) {
            $("#checkall").attr('checked', false);
            $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "#ffffff");
        }
        if (this.checked == true) {
            $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "#ffffcc");
            CheckSelectAll();
        }
        if (this.checked == false) {
            $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "#ffffff");
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated, im not good a JS at all!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "");
```